# Lev Landau's hard question about matrices

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I heard that the famous Russian physicist Lev Landau once asked one student who wanted to work in his group to find the optimal solution to the following problem:

> Given a matrix $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ with $A^*=-A$ and zero trace, assume $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ carries the Frobenius inner-product.
>
> Assume that $A$ is normalized, then we can find (by Gram-Schmidt) an ONB of all skew-Hermitian matrices with zero trace including $A$.
>
> So $A,M_1,...,M_{n^2-2}$ form an ONB of the vector space of skew-Hermitian matrices with zero trace.
>
> **Question:** Is there now a matrix $B^*=-B$ that does *not* commute with $A$ but with all other matrices of the ONB? Or if that is impossible, is there at least a matrix that is somehow good, in the sense that it does not commute with $A$ but with many other matrices of the ONB?

If anything is unclear, please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to your first question is "not always", at least when $n=2$. E.g. consider the following orthogonal basis (divide by $\sqrt{2}$ if you want normalisation) consisting of $\sqrt{-1}$ times the Pauli matrices:
$$
A=\pmatrix{&1\\ -1},\ X=\pmatrix{i\\ &-i},\ Y=\pmatrix{&i\\ i}.
$$
Any matrix $B$ that commutes with both $X$ and $Y$ must be a scalar matrix and hence it also commutes with $A$. Yet, I have no idea how to construct concrete examples in higher dimensions.